# python manage.py runserver not working on on localhost:8000

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and trying to run the django server for the first time. I am trying to run the command for starting a django server in a terminal, i.e. `python manage.py runserver`. But when I go to `http://localhost:8000`, it is not giving me the default django output containing a rocket like image.

I even tried using `http://my_ip:8000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000` but still it doesn't work. I also tried running the command as `python manage.py runserver 8000` but it still does not give me anything on localhost:8000.

I have checked and no firewall / antivirus is blocking this port for me. Also, I am able to access other applications on other ports.

I am not getting any errors on my terminal when I run this command. This is a blocker for me and any help would be really appreciated.

[Follow the image of my vs code integrated terminal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPijH.jpg)
[Find my image of browser navigated to http://localhost:8000 over here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy0HF.jpg)

I am using the latest python version 3.9 and my django version is 3.2.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `python manage.py runserver 0:8000`? and the go to localhost:8000 in your browser? are you using docker or VMs?

Comment: I've been having issues with django since 3.2. Try downgrading to 3.1.7 to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @DiegoPuente I'll try using `python manage.py runserver:8000` and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets make sure that `localhost` is in the ALLOWED_HOSTS in the setting.py file.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]
```

Create the migrations and then migrate:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Run the project using the command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Check by visiting the URLs

```
http://localhost:8000/
http://localhost:8000/admin
```